# Do software SPI read from a register using shiftin()

Tags: programming, spi

How to read from a register using software SPI, presumably [`shiftin()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/shiftin/)?

It works using the builtin [SPI library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI) + hardware SPI.

I seem to be able to write but not read using manual [`shiftin()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/shiftin/)/[`shiftout()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/shiftout/). I need to do this because I need a version of this to work on a device that doesn't have hardware SPI. I always read out `0x00000000` using [`shiftin()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/shiftin/) as below, but the SPI hardware/library works as expected.

(yes, I've double checked the pin numbers). LIS_MISO_PIN = 12.

```
  // this works (write):
  SPI.transfer(WriteAddr);
  SPI.transfer(Data);

  // this works (write):
  shiftOut(LIS_MOSI_PIN, LIS_SCK_PIN, MSBFIRST, WriteAddr);
  shiftOut(LIS_MOSI_PIN, LIS_SCK_PIN, MSBFIRST, Data);

  // this works (read):
  SPI.transfer(Reg | 0x80);
  *input = SPI.transfer(0x00);

  // does NOT work, as well as various permutations:
  shiftOut(LIS_MOSI_PIN, LIS_SCK_PIN, MSBFIRST, Reg | 0x80);
  *input = shiftIn(LIS_MISO_PIN, LIS_SCK_PIN, MSBFIRST);
```

Comment: SPI reading is done one byte at a time, how would shiftIn handle that?

Comment: Is your `LIS_MISO_PIN` set as `INPUT`? Does your device use SPI mode 0?

Comment: How about using SoftSPI? ShiftIn/Out does not work. https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/SoftSPI

Comment: How do you declare and initialize "input" ? This smells of uninitialized pointer...

Comment: Could you please add a link to the software SPI that you have used.